# NLP to recognize the meaning of a paragraph

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, nlp

How can I apply NLP to extract the summary of a paragraph,I found [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2646/extract-most-informative-parts-of-text-from-documents?newreg=590750240e6a48738cf4d598733614c5) but was wondering if there is a better and easy way before implementing it, as the ans seems to be an old one.
Basically what I need is, I have 2 paragraph and wanted to know how related they were(maybe in percentage) in context of their **meaning**.

PS:I am new to both NLP and this forum.

Comment: You can convert the documents to vectors maybe using word2vec. Then, you can measure the similarity between the vectors using euclidean distance or cosine similarity.